# determine trajectory for object followers - curve of pursuit

Tags: math, spline

I have started to develop unit trajectories for a game server and for now I'm trying to retrieve the position of a unit at a given time. It is easy when the trajectory is just a straight line, but it is far more complicated when unit chases another unit.

I've done [flash app](http://evonline.org/splines/SplinesWeb.html) to illustrate the problem. Black trajectory is for unit which travels in a single direction. Blue chases black and red chases blue. What I want is to precalculate whole trajectory for blue and red to be able to retrieve their position in a constant time.

Is it possible? Thanks for any help!!

[image]

Comment: It is most likely possible, but it depends on how you determine the change in trajectory at each point in time. From there it should be doable.

Comment: Thanks for answer! At each point in time the velocity vector of chasing object is faced to the chased object.

Comment: What do you mean "precalculate"? Just *calculate* both trajectories and record them, then do your lookup.

Comment: Honestly I don't know :) It may by anything which would allow me to retrieve the position in a constant time - parameters to algorithm, equation, anything. Recording whole trajectory is not a case because it would use too much memory for acceptable precision and also it will be too slow for a server.

Comment: @Beta, I think he wants the whole trajectory up front, or a formula for it.

Comment: Are you comfortable with polar coordinates? It looks a lot easier that way. And even so, I think you're solving the wrong problem. I mean, will there really be that many queries for the same trajectory? And will the trajectories really be so long that big-O matters?

Comment: How do you see using polar coordinates in that case? Big-O will matter as the trajectories may extend through the whole solar system and I need precision which would allow me to see it moving in very small scale. There may be also a lot of such requests to a server and each will be completely different. That may generate heavy load on server if not implemented correctly.

Comment: Have you considered an approach based on differential equations?  In your example, let f(t) be the position of the black unit at time t, and g(t) the position of the blue unit.  The black unit moves linearly, so f(t) is straightforward.  For g(t), you said "at each point in time the velocity vector of chasing object is faced to the chased object."  Mathematically, g'(t) = F(f(t), g(t)).  Meaning that the change in g(t) (blue velocity) is a function of the current positions of black, f(t), and blue, g(t).  I don't have the math skills to take this any further, but perhaps you do?

Comment: I was considering that approach too, but I also silently hoped that someone will put some light and push me forward with this as I don't have such skills in math too. I was working on it some time yesterday and I have concluded that doing it this way may not possible or too hard for me. My main problem is that f(t) and g(t) are not functions, but relations because they have two outputs (t -> x, y).

Comment: My guess is that the blue trajectory (chasing black) is doable, as a closed form solution of the differential equation (or system).  Note that the blue curve will always be planar, even in higher dimensions, but the red curve would usually be 3D except when initially constrained to 2D.  So the red trajectory is harder.

Comment: I forgot to mention this - that case is fully 2D. It will be great if I will have a formula just for the blue curve. Red ones will be less frequent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a paper [A classic chase problem solved from a
physics perspective](http://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/mungan/Publications/EJP2.pdf) by Carl E. Mungan that solves a particular version in which the chaser is initially perpendicular to the chased object's trajectory.  I believe this is an inessential element of the solution since that perpendicularity disappears along the rest of the trajectory.

It is an *autonomous* system of differential equations in the sense that time does not appear explicitly in the coefficients or terms of the equations.  This supports the idea that the family of solutions given in the paper is general enough to provide for non-perpendicular initial conditions.

The paper provides further links and references, as well as a useful search term, "curves of pursuit".

---

Let's state a slight different, slightly more general initial condition than Mungan's.  Suppose the chased object ("ship") is initially located at the origin and travels up the positive y-axis (x=0) with constant speed V.  The chasing object ("torpedo") is initially located at (x0,y0), and although instantaneous reorienting directly at the "ship", also travels at some constant speed v.

The special case where x0 is zero results in a linear pursuit curve, i.e. a head-on collision or a trailing chase accordingly as y0 is positive or negative.  Otherwise by reflection in the y-axis one may assume without loss of generality that x0 > 0.  Thus rational powers of x-coordinates will be well-defined.

Assume for our immediate purpose that speeds V,v are unequal, so that ratio r = V/v is not 1.  The following is a closed-form solution (1) for the "torpedo" curve similar to Mungan's equation (10):

```
                     (1+r)          (1-r)
              [ (x/H)          (x/H)      ]
(y/H) = (1/2) [ -----      -   -----      ]  +  C    (1)
              [ (1+r)          (1-r)      ]
```

in which the constants H,C can be determined by the initial conditions.

Applying the condition that initially the torpedo moves toward the ship's location at the origin, we take the derivative with respect to x in (1) and cancel a factor 1/H from both sides:

```
                     r        -r
dy/dx = (1/2) [ (x/H)  - (x/H)   ]                   (2)
```

Now equate the curve's slope dy/dx at initial point (x0,y0) with that of its line passing through the origin:

```
      r         -r
(x0/H)  - (x0/H)   = 2y0/x0 = K                      (3)
```

This amounts to a quadratic equation for *positive* B = (x0/H)^r:

```
B^2 - K*B - 1 = 0                                    (4)
```

namely B = [K + sqrt(K^2 + 4)]/2 (but use [the alternative form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Alternative_quadratic_formula) if K < 0 to avoid cancellation error), which allows H to be determined from our knowledge of x0 and r:

```
H = x0/(B^(1/r))                                     (5)
```

Knowing H makes it a simple matter to determine the additive constant C in (1) by substituting the initial point (x0,y0) there.

---

The tricky part will be to determine which point on the "torpedo" trajectory corresponds to a given time t > 0.  The inverse of that problem is solved fairly simply.  Given a point on the trajectory, find the tangent line at that point using derivative formula (2) and deduce time t from the y-intercept b of that line (i.e. from the current "ship" position):

```
t = b/V                                              (6)
```

Therefore determining (x(t),y(t)) where the "torpedo" is located at a given time t > 0 is essentially a root-finding exercise.  One readily brackets the desired x(t) between two x-coordinates  x1 and x2 that correspond to times t1 and t2 such that t1 < t < t2.  A root-finding method can be used to refine this interval until the desired accuracy is achieved.  Once a fairly small interval has been refined, Newton's method will provide rapid convergence.  We can look at the details of such a procedure in a next installment!

Comment: It is a lot more than I could expect! I am sure that now I will pass the problem as it looks to be very well documented issue. Thank you!

Comment: @myth:  I think it turns out that the curve itself in x,y coordinates is fairly simple, but finding where you are at a given time is trickier, because you cover a constant amount of arclength per unit time.  I'm still looking into it.

Comment: Using the term "curve of pursuit" I've also found an article at [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html). There is an equation for finding position at a given time, but with assumption that both bodies are moving with the same velocity. I don't know how to rework this. If it is possible it would be the perfect solution!

Comment: @myth: See [pursuit curve](http://www.2dcurves.com/power/powerp.html) for an equation when velocities are unequal.  This is a formula for the x,y coordinates,  but as I said the tricky part will be attaching the time coordinate.

Comment: @myth: Mungan's paper (linked in my Answer) has much the same (fairly simple) formula for x,y-coordinates of the trajectory as the 2dcurves "straight pursuit curve" webpage gives, see equation (10) in Mungan's paper.  As I noted he uses an initial condition that the pursuer starts perpendicular to the pursued objects path, and this is very convenient for giving equation (10) and other formulas.  I'm trying to set the result up for you with a more general initial condition.

Comment: That would be wonderful! I also hope that I am not taking too much of your time for this question as I really appreciate your previous help. I am trying to figure it out also for my own, but I don't know if I will be able to do this.

Comment: Now it is the perfect solution! I've improved the topic's header to let the others to easily find it in need. It is very common problem, but without solution until now. Thank you again a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I can set up the problem for you but not solve it.

The black curve is moving at a constant velocity v0, and in a straight line.

The blue curve moves at a constant velocity v1 in the direction of black.

For simplicity, choose coordinates so that at time t=0 the black curve starts at (x=0, y=0) and is moving in the direction x.

Thus, at time t >= 0, the position of the black curve is (v0 t, 0).

**Problem statement**

The goal is to find x, y of the blue curve for times t >= 0 given the initial position (x(t=0), y(t=0)). The differential equations of motion are

dx / dt = v1 (v0 t - x) / a(t)

dy / dt = v1 (- y) / a(t)

where a(t) = sqrt((v0 t - x)^2 + (y^2)) is the distance between blue and black at time t.

This is a system of two nonlinear coupled differential equations. It seems likely that there is no complete anaytical solution. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) gives up without trying for the input

```
D[y[t],t] = -y[t] / sqrt[(t-x[t])^2 + y[t]^2], D[x[t],t] = (t-x[t]) / sqrt[(t-x[t])^2 + y[t]^2]
```

You could try asking on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-equations). Good luck!

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines, but with a uniform motion added that keeps the black "trajectory" constant at the origin.  That is, the velocity of the blue object is (-v0,0) plus an inwardly radial component of size v1, to use your labels.  As you noted, we need to specify an initial position for "blue", but WolframAlpha may have given up "without trying" because it wasn't included in that specification.

Comment: For simpler differential equations, Wolfram Alpha will give an answer with unknown constants to be determined by the initial conditions. For example, `D[y[t],t] = -y[t]` gives `y[t] = c1 exp[-t]`.

Comment: You may also contemplate solving the ODE numerically. If you are going real time, this is what you should do (use RK4 if the time step is imposed by eg. frame rate, otherwise use something like Burlisch-Stoer).